# Block HTTP request in chrome extension and return `200 OK` status code

Tags: google-chrome-extension, httprequest

I am using the [CORS Unblock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino) extension and noticed that some POST requests still were failing the preflight check.

This is because the preflight check will fail unless the response has the required `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Header **AND** a status code of `200 OK`.

This results in `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`.

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    e => {
        if(e.method == "OPTIONS")
            return {cancel: true};
    },

    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "extraHeaders"]
);
```

Redirecting the request results in `Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request`.

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    e => {
        if(e.method == "OPTIONS")
            return {redirectUrl: "javascript:"};
    },

    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "extraHeaders"]
);
```

Can I block the `OPTIONS` request and return a `200 OK` status code?.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: webRequest API can't change the status code. AFAICT the only way is to use [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) on each tab/frame where you need it with the [Fetch.fulfillRequest](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch#method-fulfillRequest) command.

Comment: @wOxxOm But I do not want to change the status code, I want to prevent the request from reaching the original URL, and return a 200 OK status. Is that not currently possible?

Comment: Replace `change` with `process` in my comment.

Comment: @wOxxOm OK. Is there any other way to bypass the preflight request?

Comment: This could be a bug in Chrome. Try reporting on https://crbug.com.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure what is the bug here?

Comment: Uhm? The lack of the ability to alter the request to make it work.

Comment: Oh. I thought bugs were unintended behaviour. I would consider this a feature request. Either way, I need a solution quickly, and a report will take too much time. I am looking into using chrome.debugger as you suggested, or if that fails, setting up a CORS proxy as an extension (like [200 OK](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)).